# Parent mnemonics not working when CefSharp browser has focus

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Probably a simple question I am sure.   So I've created a simple CefSharp browser on a WinForm.

The problem is - when the browser has focus all the menu mnemonics on the parent form are disabled (e.g. "Alt+F" for the file menu, etc)

I have KeyPreview set True on my parent form - is there some setting I need to disable/enable on the browser object to have it pass mnemonics/accelerators/shortcuts up to the parent form?

Comment: It's actually quite a complex top, one I don't have time to discuss in length. If you look at the `WinForms` example as part of the main project you'll see a sample implementation for `IKeyBoardHandler`, from memory it will forward unhandled key strokes to your parent app.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out - my problem was not related to CefSharp.

I implemented the IKeyboardHandler and that didn't help either.  I could see where the handler was reflecting calls back to the parent - but still I didn't get the response to my hotkeys on my menu.

That is when I started looking elsewhere and realized that the Telerik RadMenu I was using on the form did not support Mnemonics. (Off topic:  Telerik controls are cool but beware, there are a lot of little bugs like this lurking in them.  For the money they charge you wouldn't expect this.)

Solution was to dump Telerik RadMenu and just use a WinForms Menu and problem solved!!